# Place DIV Between & Above Two Lower DIVs

Tags: css, html, overlay, overlap

I am designing a webpage that requires at least three DIVs and possibly one container DIV. I need one DIV on the left, one in the middle, and one on the right. It seems simple enough but I also need the two side DIVs to underlap the middle DIV.

```
                                  +-----------------------+
          +-----------------------|-----+           +---------------------------+
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |     o     |     |                     |
          |                       |     |     v     |     |                     |
          |                       |     |     e     |     |                     |
          |       50% width       |     |     r     |     |       50% width     |
          |                       |     |     l     |     |                     |
          |                       |     |     a     |     |                     |
          |                       |     |     y     |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          |                       |     |           |     |                     |
          +-----------------------|-----+           +---------------------------+
                                  +-----------------------+
```

I saw this from a another StackOverflow answer, but I can't seem to translate it horizontally: http://jsfiddle.net/PWwQM/1/

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use the float property to get the outer divs side by side: `float:left;` I think this is what you want, anyway:

http://jsfiddle.net/SuTLq/

Your diagram shows a gutter between the outer divs, but I didn't create one since you write that the outer divs are each 50% of the width.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just use `position absolute` for middle one.Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYTVy/).